# Gender in Vayishlach 33:6-7

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, grammar-dikduk, vayishlach, bowing-kneeling

In Vayishlach ([Bereishis 33:6](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8228#v=6)-7), Yaakov's wives and children bow to Esav. With regard to the maidservants and their sons, the verse states וַתִּשְׁתַּחֲוֶיןָ - in the feminine, whereas by Leah and her sons, as well as by Yosef and Rachel, it says וַיִּשְׁתַּחֲווּ - in the masculine. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *Rosh* and *Chizkuni* (in his second explanation) and *Daas Z'kenim* answer that the maidservants' sons didn't bow, as they thought that they, as freemen, were more important than their mothers. That's why it says "bowed" in the feminine: only women bowed. [Presumably "and their children" in the verse refers to approaching.]

*Chizkuni*'s first explanation is that the maidservants' sons didn't bow because they thought *Esav* wouldn't care about their bowing since they were mere sons of maidservants.

Comment: First answer -- makes you think what the family dynamics were like. "Dan, Naftali! Come downstairs for dinner!" *No can do, mom!* *You're* a maidservant. *We're* sons of Israel.